# remove li element from list when clicking on an icon inside that li jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I'm trying to remove a `<li>` element from an `<ul>`, using a click event on an icon which is placed inside that same `<li>` element. The `<li>` elements are created dinamically.

The html looks like

```
<ul id="lista_enlaces_ul" class="collection with-header">
    <li class="collection-header">
        <h4>Enlaces añadidos</h4>                            
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item"><div>Enlace Random<i class="secondary-content delete_icon material-icons">delete_forever</i></div></li>
</ul>
```

so when clicking on that `<i>` that has the `delete_icon` class, its `<li>` parent should be removed.

this is the `.on()` event

```
$("#lista_enlaces_ul").on("click", "i.delete_icon", function (e) {

});
```

i've tried several ways to try to find the index of the li element inside ul to remove it, but i'm going nowhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this).closest('li').remove();` or `$(this).parents('li').remove();`

```js
$("#lista_enlaces_ul").on("click", "i.delete_icon", function(e) {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista_enlaces_ul" class="collection with-header">
    <li class="collection-header">
        <h4>Enlaces añadidos</h4>                            
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item"><div>Enlace Random<i class="secondary-content delete_icon material-icons">delete_forever</i></div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#lista_enlaces_ul").on("click", "i.delete_icon", function (e) {
$(e.target).parents('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: Hi there! thank you for your answer but can you provide a brief explanation behind your solution?

Comment: Yes, so from the event it will get target element and and from that it will select the parent element that is 'li', and just simply remove that.